# SQLDecodeError at /admin/auth/user/

Tags: python, django, database, mongodb, djongo

An sql decode error is raised whenever I filter the groups in the admin module. I have made no modification to the admin interface or models regarding users or groups, except for a few one-to-one relationships with the user model. The error is only raised when filtering groups.
Is there any way to prevent this error from being raised?

The error is as is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/?groups__id__exact=1

Django Version: 2.2.10
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['game.apps.GameConfig',
 'user.apps.UserConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in parse
  824.                 return handler(self, statement)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in _select
  963.         self._query = SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __init__
  111.         super().__init__(*args)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __init__
  72.         self.parse()

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in parse
  119.                 c = self.selected_columns = ColumnSelectConverter(self, tok_id)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py" in __init__
  44.         super().__init__(query_ref, begin_id)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py" in __init__
  24.         self.parse()

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py" in parse
  63.             raise SQLDecodeError

The above exception () was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  606.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1685.             cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in get_changelist_instance
  731.         return ChangeList(

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in __init__
  82.         self.get_results(request)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py" in get_results
  210.         result_count = paginator.count

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  80.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  91.             return c()

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  392.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  504.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  489.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1133.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py" in execute
  48.         self.result = Result(

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in __init__
  753.         self.parse()

File "/Users/jayjay/anaconda3/envs/djongo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py" in parse
  846.                 raise exe from e

Exception Type: SQLDecodeError at /admin/auth/user/
Exception Value: FAILED SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "auth_user"."id" AS Col1, "auth_user"."password" AS Col2, "auth_user"."last_login" AS Col3, "auth_user"."is_superuser" AS Col4, "auth_user"."username" AS Col5, "auth_user"."first_name" AS Col6, "auth_user"."last_name" AS Col7, "auth_user"."email" AS Col8, "auth_user"."is_staff" AS Col9, "auth_user"."is_active" AS Col10, "auth_user"."date_joined" AS Col11 FROM "auth_user" INNER JOIN "auth_user_groups" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."user_id") WHERE "auth_user_groups"."group_id" = %(0)s) subquery
Params: (1,)
Version: 1.3.1
```

Here is the output of pip freeze:

```
certifi==2019.11.28
dataclasses==0.6
Django==2.2.10
django-jsoneditor==0.1.5
djongo==1.3.1
jsonfield==3.1.0
packaging==20.1
pymongo==3.10.1
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
```

Comment: Is that the full error message?

Comment: What does MongoDb have to do with it?

Comment: You've made a nice statement, but haven't asked a question.  Additionally, you should consider proving the error message from your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a temporary hack that I found:
I changed line 753 in djongo/sql2mongo/query.py from this:

```py
        self.parse()
```

to this:

```py
        try:
            self.parse()
        except:
            if (self._sql.strip().endswith("subquery")):
                self._sql = self._sql.strip()[:-8]
```

Comment: Did you override the `BaseQuery` class there, and how?